# SSH Connection from MAC to Amazon EC2 not working

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-ec2, terminal

I am trying to connect to Amazon EC2 via:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/YOUR_KEYPAIR_FILE.pem ec2-user@YOUR_IP_ADDRESS
```

The terminal takes 1 or 2 mins and then prints:

```
ssh: connect to host XXX port 22: Operation timed out
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding a `-vvv` for diagnostic output

Comment: Connecting with `-vvv` will give you more information. Also check your security group settings to see if port 22 is open to your location.

Answer (score 3):

1. Login to AWS
2. Go to the Instances section
3. Click on the security group associated with your EC2 instance
4. Down the bottom click on the inbound tab and then click edit

### Create this rule

```
TYPE         SSH
PROTOCOL     TCP  
PORT RANGE   22  
SOURCE       Anywhere
```

You should now be able to connect to the instance on port 22 via ssh with your key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open port 22 in your security group. All ports are closed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing permissions to YOUR_KEYPAIR_FILE.pem like this
chmod 600 YOUR_KEYPAIR_FILE.pem

Then shoot the command
ssh -i YOUR_KEYPAIR_FILE.pem ec2-user@YOUR_IP_ADDRESS

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I checked all my networking time and time again from the ec2 instance all the way through the VPC and out to the internet. Security groups were allowing all sources through ports 22 and 80. My NACL was allowing the right permissions. I knew AWS was all ok yet everytime I went to try ssh into an instance I would still get an operation timeout, indicating that problem must be with my local machine instead.

First to check that the ssh port was open I ran the following:

```
ssh localhost
```

This worked fine!

Afte doing some research on the net, in the end it all boiled down to java and my terminal not recognising that java was installed on my machine.

Supporting Document: 
[AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)

[No Java means that your .pem will not be recognised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYXbh.png)

Start by running the follwing:

`java -version`

If you get no hits then install relevant java SDK for your OS and once installed run

`which java`

You should get something like this:

`/usr/bin/java`

Now we can try connect to an instance again and hopefully you should have success this time!

```
ssh -v -i ~/Downloads/labamikey.pem ec2-user@ec2-34-200-217-2.compute-

   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
  ___|\___|___|
```

`[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-54 ~]$`